# Как сделать разный фон для разных буферов в vim?

Tags: vim

Как сделать **разный** фон для разных буферов в vim? И можно ли вообще такое? Пробовал менять цвет фона - распространяется на все буферы, а хочется другого.
Например, в зависимости от типа файла иметь разный фон (оттенок).

Answer (score 2):

В стандартной поставке это невозможно - colorshemе распостроняется на все буфера.

Можете попробовать менять цвет при перключении буферов. Поменяется также в не активных буферах, но при возврате востановится. `b:colors_name` лучше установить в ftplugin/*.vim.

```
au BufEnter * if (exists("b:colors_name")) | let b:current_colors=colors_name
 \| execute "colorscheme " . b:colors_name | endif
au BufLeave * if (exists("b:current_colors")) | execute "colorscheme " . b:current_colors | endif
```

PS Здесь [plugin tab colorsheme](https://github.com/ujihisa/tabpagecolorscheme)   то, что очень похоже на решение, только оно для вкладок.
Если там подсмотреть, можно своё что нибудь смастерить для буферов.

Answer (score 1):

Быстро сделать это стандартными средствами невозможно. По соображением переносимости Vim проектировался как консольная программма на терминал с 16 цветами или вообще на двухцветную консоль. GUI для него это просто незначительный, маловажный побочный эффект.

Разноцветные буферы при условии 16 доступных цветов будут просто портить подсветку синтаксиса. Максимум что можно сделать быстро - это придумать какой-нибудь костыль вроде такого, чтобы подсветить текущую строчку, чтобы сделать отличие текущего буфера более очевидным.

```
augroup BgHighlight
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter * set cul
    autocmd WinLeave * set nocul
augroup END
```

Comment: Вместо скрытия\показа линии курсора использую плагин AirLine, он для активного буфера подсвечивает статус-строку.
Фон хотел использовать для буферов разных языков.

Comment: Понял, ничем не могу помочь, в лучшем случае опять костыль который определеяет тип файла и ставит соответствующий ему цвет. Затем открываете каждый файл новым процессом и затем переключаетесь между ними с помощью тайлового оконного менеджера вроде i3 горячие клавиши которого совпадают с обычным Vim и радуйтесь жизни. Но это просто АДСКИЙ костыль.